# How to make a datepicker always be clear of the textbox

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, datepicker

Ok I have a jQuery date picker attached to a textbox. So when you focus on the textbox the datepicker pops up. This works well most of the time, but if the textbox is near the bottom of the screen then the datepicker will not cause the screen to scroll more, instead it will just be shifted up and cover the textbox, making it not visible.

How do I fix this situation? I don't care how it's fixed if it is a flip-flop between the datepicker showing under or on top of the textbox(vertically that is) or if it is something simple as making the windows scroll some more.

Basically though I need it to be so that you can always see the datepicker and always see the textbox it is attached to when the textbox is focused.

As a side note, whenever there is space above the textbox the datepicker actually will go above it. But when there isn't space above or below then it will just sit itself in the middle making the textbox not visible

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change the pop-up position of the jQuery DatePicker control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/662220/how-to-change-the-pop-up-position-of-the-jquery-datepicker-control)

Answer (score 1):

[How to change the pop-up position of the jQuery DatePicker control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662220/how-to-change-the-pop-up-position-of-the-jquery-datepicker-control)

Found this post for you, hopefully one of those answers works!