# 2 Multi datepickers in same page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, datepicker

I have 2 datepickers in my web page and somehow one continue the other. I want them to work differently. Maybe its because of the object `dateText` but don't know how to clean it.

There are two scripts calling the same class

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css">
<script src="js/jquery.datepicker.extension.range.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(function() {
    $('#date_range').datepicker({
        range: 'multiple',
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst, extensionRange) {    
            $('#dataF').val(extensionRange.datesText.join(','));
            $('#date_range').val('DATA');
            $('#datepicker').datepicker('selected','');
        }
    });
});
$("#date_range2").click(function(){
    $('#date_range2').val(" ").datepicker({startDate: "+7d"});                  
});
</script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#date_range2').datepicker({
        range: 'multiple',
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst, extensionRange) {
            $('#dataS').val(extensionRange.datesText.join(','));
            $('#date_range2').val('TILL');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Then I have

```
<input id="date_range" value="DATA:" />

<input name="dataF" id="dataF" type="text" size="50" /> 

<input id="date_range2" value="TILL:" />

<input  name="dataS" id="dataS" type="text" size="50" />
```

Comment: Does one over write the other both of them do the same thing ? did you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4900101/jquery-ui-multiple-datepickers-on-single-page)

Comment: Hope this link can help you
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16373734/jquery-datepicker-restrict-dates-in-second-date-field-based-on-selected-date-in)

Comment: no.. my friend they have to work separately!
one is for when trip starts 
second is when trip ends 

if same day soo its trip if not its tour ! 

somehow the second gives the dates that the first one give !

Answer (score 0):

Just try this sollution 
example link http://jsfiddle.net/fMD62/

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker1" name="datepicker1" value="" />
<input type="text" id="datepicker2" name="datepicker2" value="" />


$(function() {
    $("#datepicker1").datepicker();
    $("#datepicker2").datepicker();
});
```

Comment: no.. thanks, need multi datepicker  not close " in second line

Comment: so you want date range picker?

Comment: no.. just called it like that.. i need 2 multi date pickers one that you can tap 4 different dates.. and another that you can tap 4 different none connected with first..