# Getting value from JQUERY datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

If I want to display the JQUERY UI datepicker inline by attaching it to a DIV like `$("div#someID").datepicker()` - how do I access the chosen date? I assume if it's not bound to an `INPUT` then it won't be submitted with the form.

I guess as a followup, if I need to bind it to an INPUT element, is there a way to control the positioning of the datepicker relative to the INPUT element? If I wanted the datepicker to appear above or to the side of the element rather than below it, how would I do that?

Forgive me if this answer is somewhere really obvious.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

If you want to get the date when the user selects it, you can do this:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    onSelect: function() { 
        var dateObject = $(this).datepicker('getDate'); 
    }
});
```

I am not sure about the second part of your question. But, have you tried using style sheets and relative positioning?

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe I somehow missed "getDate" when looking through the docs! I figure I'll probably have to go mess around with their style sheets, but I always get nervous hacking anything someone else has done.

Comment: how do you parse the date `"Wed Nov 08 2017 18:20:28 GMT+0100 (W. Europe Standard Time)"`?

Comment: Be sure you account for that the date is returned in __localtime__, not UTC(). To take the date as UTC, use `Date.UTC( dateObject.getFullYear(), dateObject.getMonth(), dateObject.getDate() );`

Answer (score 15):

You can use the `getDate` method:

```
var d = $('div#someID').datepicker('getDate');
```

That will give you a Date object in `d`.

There aren't any [options for positioning](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) the popup but you might be able to do something with CSS or the `beforeShow` event if necessary.

Answer (score 6):

```
$('div#someID').datepicker({
   onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { alert(dateText); }
});
```

you must bind it to input element only

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/662220/how-to-change-the-pop-up-position-of-the-jquery-datepicker-control hope this may help u

Answer (score 5):

You could remove the name attribute of this input, so it won't be submited.

To access the value of this controll:

```
$("div#someID").datepicker( "getDate" )
```

and your may have a look at the document in http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe I somehow missed "getDate" when looking through the docs!

Answer (score 2):

You could do it as follows - with validation just to ensure that the datepicker is bound to the element.

```
var dt;

if ($("div#someID").is('.hasDatepicker')) {
    dt = $("div#someID").datepicker('getDate');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If your selected elements are not one, you need use this way:

```
$('[type="date"]').datepicker();
$('[type="date"]').change(function() {
    var date = $(this).datepicker("getDate");
    console.log(date);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also try this.

```
$('#datepickerID').val();
```

This is the simplest way.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: The #datepickerID part is the ID of the text field containing the selected date, and .val() is a function that grabs the value (the date) that's in that text field.  So if I chose 09/01/2020 from the Date Picker, that value goes into my text field.  The code above grabs that chosen date.

Comment: but this will return the date in string format. In case of localization this cloud be an issue

Answer (score 2):

see tag input
example :

```
<div class="input-group date" data-target-input="nearest">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input form-control-sm" data-target="#dt_expdate" id="dt_expdate" />
                        <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#dt_expdate" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
                            <div class="input-group-text form-control-sm"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

acess to get & assign value from

```
id="dt_expdate"
```

get value:

```
var date= $("#dt_expdate").val();
```

assign value:

```
$("#dt_expdate").val('20/08/2020');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
date = $("#datepicker").val();
```

this code will work, and also you can use this value by storing it into a variable `date` and it also used to limit another datepickers' value  `minDate` or `MaxDate`.

Answer (score 0):

To position the datepicker next to the input field you could use following code.

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    beforeShow: function(input, inst)
    {
        inst.dpDiv.css({marginLeft: input.offsetWidth + 'px'});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do this for a sales report that allows the user to choose a date range.  The solution is similar to another answer, but I wanted to provide my example just to show you the practical real world use that I applied this to:

````
var reportHeader = `Product Sales History Report for ${$('#FromDate').val()} to ${$('#ToDate').val()}.` ;
```
````