# Getting hidden value for a datepicker

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have a datepicker as shown in this [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pratik24/M9Hj6/). I need to get the value of that datepicker and display it below calendar without any text box. How can I do it?
I tried

```
alert($("#datepicker").val());
```

and

```
alert($("#datepicker").getText());
```

and

```
alert($("#datepicker").getValue());
```

But it didn't work. How can I implement this?

Comment: Are you sure that `#datepicker` is the correct selector for your hidden input?

Comment: Did you try [`getDate`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/)?

Comment: No, let me try `getDate`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [onSelect](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect)

```js
$("#dp").datepicker({
  buttonImage: '//placehold.it/32',
  buttonImageOnly: true,
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  showOn: 'both',
  onSelect: function(value) {
    $('#mydiv').text(value)
  }
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input type="hidden" id="dp" />
<div id="mydiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `$('#').datepicker('getDate');`

This is very similar to an existing question if you want to see more answers: [Getting value from JQUERY datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8147108/getting-value-from-jquery-datepicker)