# get the week day of date selected from bootstrap datepicker

Tags: javascript, php, bootstrap-datepicker

```
 <div class="control-group">
 <label class="span4">Required Date <span class="red">*</span></label>
  <div class="input-append date datepick span7 required" name="datetimepicker" id="datetimepicker">
    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th icon-calendar"></i></span>
  <input class="span12 form-control required" name="date" id="date"  type="text" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" data-format="dd/MM/yyyy" readonly>
</div>

$('#date').change(function(){
  var date = $(this).val();
  alert(date);
});
```

I dont know what the problem but is but this change event is not working. Maybe the readonly property of input is messing with something. Please help guys.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting value from JQUERY datepicker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8147108/getting-value-from-jquery-datepicker)

Comment: @aldrin27- Let me see if that works for me.

Comment: @aldrin27- no buddy its not working for me. I have tried it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function changeDate(newdate) {
        var date = newdate;
        alert(date);
    }

    $('input#date').change(function() {
        changeDate($(this).val());
    });

    changeDate($('input#date').val());
});
```

This ought to work.

Comment: I am getting the date from bootstrap datepicker. But I dont want the user to type anything so I am making the input field readonly.

Comment: change event is only work when user input value change!!so how you put datepicker value in #date

Comment: Your code will works only once and that time input field will be empty and what will happen if user changes date

Comment: @DavidJawphan- '$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
        format: 'dd/MM/yyyy',
        language: 'en' ,
    pickTime: false
      });'

Comment: @YatinKhullar- It is not working even once. Anyway I want it to work every time user changes date

Comment: Updated, please check.