# How to count the number of days between 2 dates in MaterializeCSS datepicker?

Tags: jquery, datepicker, materialize

I am trying to figure out the number of days between 2 dates in MaterializeCSS datepicker. 
The below is the one which works in jQuery datepicker.

jQuery Datepicker:

```
var d1 = $('#req_startdate').datepicker('getDate');
var d2 = $('#req_enddate').datepicker('getDate');

if (d1 && d2) {
    diff = Math.floor((d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()) / 86400000); // ms per day
    $('#calculated').val(diff);
}
```

MaterializeCSS Datepicker:

```
var d1 = $('#startdate').val();
var d2 = $('#enddate').val();
```

Could any one help ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting value from JQUERY datepicker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8147108/getting-value-from-jquery-datepicker)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the result with the logic below:

```
        var d1 = $('#reqstartdate').val();
        var d2 = $('#reqenddate').val();

        var date1 = new Date(d1);
        var date2 = new Date(d2);

        var date1_ms = date1.getTime();
        var date2_ms = date2.getTime();

        var diff = date2_ms-date1_ms;

          // get days
        var days = diff/1000/60/60/24;

        $('#calculated').val(days);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#txtToDate").change(function () {
    var start = new Date(getDate($('#txtFromDate').val()));
    var end = new Date(getDate($('#txtToDate').val()));

    diff = new Date(end - start),
        days = diff / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;
    if (days == NaN) {
        $('#txtTotalDays').val(0);
    } else {
        $('#txtTotalDays').val(days);
    }
})
```

Note: same code copy & paste and make another function for **txtFromDate**