# Change position of Datepicker inside Modelpopup textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, datepicker, modalpopupextender

I am working on a ASP.Net webform which includes `AJAX Modelpoup Extender` and `jquery nepali-datepicker`. I have to integrate `nepali-datepicker` to a textbox that is inside my second `modelpopup` i.e. with blue background shown in image below.
Problem I am facing is that I am not able to position `datepicker` at bottom of `textbox`

Based on answers on the post([How to change the pop-up position of the jQuery DatePicker control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662220/how-to-change-the-pop-up-position-of-the-jquery-datepicker-control?lq=1)) I was able to bring datepicker in front of 2nd model popup. Is there a way that I can use to actually position datepicker to the textbox.

Here is my script and styles:

```
<script type="text/javascript">        
    function pageLoad() {
        $('.nepali-calendar').nepaliDatePicker();
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.nepali-calendar').nepaliDatePicker();

    });
</script>    

<style type="text/css">
    div#ndp-nepali-box
    {
        position:absolute;
        z-index: 999999;
    }
</style>
```

Following image shows how it is is positioned right now.[image]

If I use `position` as `relative`.

```
<style type="text/css">
    div#ndp-nepali-box
    {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 999999;
    }
</style>
```

It looks like
[image]

Is there a way that I can use to actually position datepicker to bottom of the textbox.

Answer (score 6):

As you are using `jquery UI Datepicker` it should have `beforeShow` property and change css inside this property like below.

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5xrpcurj/)

```
$('input.date').datepicker({
beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
 var cal = inst.dpDiv;
 var top  = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
 var left = $(this).offset().left;
 setTimeout(function() {
    cal.css({
        'top' : top,
        'left': left
    });
 }, 10);
}
});
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662220/how-to-change-the-pop-up-position-of-the-jquery-datepicker-control)

Comment: I am using a slight different datepicker from `jquery UI Datepicker`. I searched for `beforeShow` property but couldn't found it. Anyways I went to datepicker's developer's website to contact him and found out he has released a new version of datepicker. I implemented the newer version which I don't know why solved the problem itself. Thanks anyways :)

Comment: Due to differences in `jquery datepicker` plugins, this solution was not for me.. hope this solution works for other users. So I'll reward my bounty to you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try relative position:

```
<style type="text/css">
    div#ndp-nepali-box
    {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 999999;
    }
</style>
```

I don't know, what is div#ndp-nepali-box, but try to do this:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .ui-datepicker
    {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 999999;
    }
</style>
```

it can be important

Comment: I've tried that... it doesn't work.... `datepicker` dialogbox begins from top of the second `modelpopup, and ends at the bottom of the main form. I've updated the question to show the design.

Comment: @TFrost updated. also, do you have your site in web? so, we can look at real situation

Comment: @Backs : no I haven't deployed it on web.. If you require more information I can update the question..