# move the position of bootstrap datepicker

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-modal

[image]Can I able to move the datepicker near the calender icon ??? Any fix for this would be appreciated. datepicker is generated dynamically.

> I have given id to div

[image]

```
<div class="datepick col-sm-6">
                            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1' >
                                <input type='text' class="form-control" placeholder="Select Start Date"/>
                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                    </div>
    <script>
     $('#datetimepicker1').datepicker({
            autoclose: true,
            startDate: '-0m',
            todayHighlight: true
        }).on('changeDate', function(ev){
            $('#sDate1').text($('#datetimepicker1').data('date'));
            $('#datetimepicker1').datepicker('hide');
        });
    </script>
```

[image]

Comment: what to you mean near the calender icon?

Comment: At the end of the div . Now it is at the begining right

Comment: the icon which is at the right corner is what i mentioned as calender icon

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you need is little bit of jquery

see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/3L4gc6fy/1/)

JQuery

```
$('#datetimepicker1').click(function(){
    var popup =$(this).offset();
    var popupTop = popup.top - 40;
    $('.ui-datepicker').css({
      'top' : popupTop
     });
});
```

About positioning of datepicker read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662220/how-to-change-the-pop-up-position-of-the-jquery-datepicker-control)

Comment: The accepted answer for this question is actually not for the jQuery UI Datepicker. To change the position of the jQuery UI Datepicker just modify .ui-datepicker in the css file. The size of the Datepicker can also be changed in this way, just adjust the font size.

Comment: The above answer helped me . Thanks a lot

Comment: If this helps you then please accept this as answer so users with similar issue can find it useful. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

Simply you can use followed code sample;

```
$('#input').datepicker({
    orientation: "top right"
});
```

Comment: Then you can get dynamically datepicker's current left position and input width and you can set new left position dynamically like that [new_left = current_left + input_width]

Comment: This is working for me, with bootstrap-datepicker 1.8.0

Answer (score 4):

For change the default Bootstrap datetimepicker:

**1-) From Jquery**

```
$("#datetimepicker1").datetimepicker({
     pickerPosition: 'top-left'
});
```

*Others positions options: bottom-left, top-right*

Answer (score 1):

The 'container' option available in the plugin might come in handy. You can use CSS to position the calendar wherever you need it. Here is an example I have created on jsFiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/giri_jeedigunta/6patf4L5/

HTML:

```
<div class="dt-cont">
  <input type="text" class="datepicker">
</div>
<div id="custom-pos"></div>
```

JS:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
  container: '#custom-pos'
});
```

CSS:

```
#custom-pos {
  position: relative;
  right: -70px;
}
.dropdown-menu {
   left: auto !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may override the default class of css of date picker. Add inline style to the div of date picker, for example,

change

```
<div class="datepick col-sm-6">
```

to

```
<div class="datepick col-sm-6" style="position: absolute; left: 865.15px; display: block;">
```

It will override the default css. You need to try different values for left property, to make it best fit on the form.

Comment: How can i apply left property when the style attributes are fetching dynamically