# Problem in positioning the React Datepicker

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, react-datepicker

The date picker appears above the input field and is hidden under the above div, how can I change it to appear down not up?

[image]

```
  <DatePicker
                        selected={ this.state.valueDate }
                        onChange={(val) => this.handleChange(val)}
                        name="startDate"
                        dateFormat="dd.MM.yyyy"
                        className="form-control"
                        autoComplete="off"
                        portalId="root-portal"
                    />
```

Comment: Are you using any UI Kit like Bootstrap, Material Ui, Ant Design, or something?

Comment: @Danielprabhakaran N Yes, Bootstrap

Comment: This may help you :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40149983/move-the-position-of-bootstrap-datepicker

Comment: Can you share the full code? From where do you import DatePicker?